# How to allow multiple authorize options

Tags: c#, .net-core, authorization

I have a core 3.1 api running currently with JWT Bear Tokens.
To use, I simple supply the token from an OAuth2 provider and this working fine.

The defaultPolicy is setup and uses RequireAuthenticatedUser();

However I have a require to allow for end-point that needs to use another authorization process.

So I created a custom AuthorizationHandler and added this as a policy. Then add this policy against the end point. When I hit that end point the custom AuthorizationHandler gets triggered and everything seems to work and the context.Succeed(requirement) is called and then returns Task.CompletedTask.

The problem is that I am still getting a 401 Unauthorize.

Can anyone help?

Below is the custom Handler:

```
 public class MyCustomAuthorizeRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{ }

public class MyCustomAuthorizeRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyCustomAuthorizeRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    private readonly MyCustomSettings _MyCustomSettings;
    public MyCustomAuthorizeRequirementHandler(MyCustomSettings MyCustomSettings)
    {
        _MyCustomSettings = MyCustomSettings;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyCustomAuthorizeRequirement requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = context.Resource as HttpContext;


        string authHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.StartsWith("x-auth-"))
        {
            if(authHeader != _MyCustomSettings.MyCustomAuthKey)
            {
                context.Fail();
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Below is the extract from the program.cs

```
 builder.Services
            .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer();

        // Configure policies
        builder.Services
            .AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var userAuthPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder();
                options.DefaultPolicy = userAuthPolicyBuilder
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

                
                options.AddPolicy("MyCustomAuthorize", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MyCustomAuthorizeRequirement()));
            });

        MyCustomSettings localMyCustomSettings = new MyCustomSettings();
        configuration.GetSection("MyCustomSettings").Bind(localMyCustomSettings);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler>(new MyCustomAuthorizeRequirementHandler(localMyCustomSettings));
```

Comment: Sorry code added above

Comment: Side note, you might have the logic in your HandleRequirementAsync backwards. Right now if an incoming request doesn't have the `x-auth-` header, they pass your authorize check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, there are two "auth" related HTTP status codes: 401 and 403.

- 401 means "you don't have the right papers"
- 403 means "yes, these papers are legit, but I'm not allowed to let you in the door".

Your default policy has `.RequireAuthenticatedUser()`. Keyword here is "Authenticated". Your application only has *one* authentication strategy - JWTs. If you don't provide a JWT, you are not authenticated, and thus not authorized.

Here's what you can do:

1. Create another `AuthenticationHandler` that will read the `Authorization` header, ensure the value starts with "x-key-", and if so save it as a *claim*.
2. Modify your `AuthorizationHandler` to read from the *claim* (not directly from the HTTP request).
3. Modify the `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` to have `.AddAuthenticationSchemes()`, listing both schemes.

Comment: I needed to create a second schema and then use that against the end points